# Why does php continue interpreting after die();

Tags: php, syntax, interpreter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [stop php processing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823635/stop-php-processing-file)

Today while playing around with PHP a noticed a strange thing

I had a block of Code where it does a job.

```
$images = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    foreach($images as $image):
        $img = get_post($image->meta_value);
        print_r($img);
    endforeach;
```

And after this piece of code i tried to die; because i needed to analyse the output.

```
$images = $wpdb->get_results($query);

            foreach($images as $image):
                $img = get_post($image->meta_value);
                print_r($img);
            endforeach;
    die;bla bla bla qit error !98123
```

Which means stop by this line and dont go further.

But it goes and i thought as a Scripting Language it parses Line by Line and will not go after the `die;`

But in fact it goes.

Does some one has any explanation for that ?

Comment: this is syntax error, can you post the original code?

Comment: The whole thing is parsed before executed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `die()` and `exit()` functions only stop **execution** of the script, which happens only **after** the file has been **fully parsed**.

If you with to stop **parsing** itself, you must use `__halt_compiler()`, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.halt-compiler.php

Comment: note that __halt_compiler() can only be used from the outermost scope.

Comment: Good point! It is also in the docs I linked.

Answer (score 0):

If that's your actual code, then you have a syntax error. PHP parses your code BEFORE it executes it. Meaning, it won't matter if you use die or exit. If that's not your code (maybe you just used it as an example) and things are still acting "strange", you should know that die works exactly the same way as [exit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php), which:

> Terminates execution of the script. Shutdown functions and object
>   destructors **will always be executed even if exit is called**.